# TypeORM / How to mock QueryRunner.manager.findOne in Jest Test

Tags: typescript, jestjs, typeorm

I am trying to test some functions that receive queryRunner as a parameter and execute queryRunner.manager.findOne:

```
  const logistic = await queryRunner.manager.findOne(Logistic, {
    where: {
      id: logisticsId || scooterLogisticId,
    },
  });
```

In my jest test, i am mocking my data-source module and database module,

```
const dataSource = addTransactionalDataSource({
  dataSource: new DataSource(ormConfig),
  patch: true,
});
```

and database returns

```
export const database = new DatabaseManager();
```

Here is my test file

```
import { dataSource } from "../../../../data-source";

jest.mock("../../../../data-source");
jest.mock("../../../../helpers/database")
describe("isScooter", () => {
  // Shared mock data
  const mockEmail = "test@example.com";
  const mockParsedBody = {
    completedAt: new Date(),
    slotIdInbound: "DEF456",
    fees: [{ value: 10 }, { value: 20 }],
    inspectionNote: "Some inspection notes",
    agent: "John Doe",
    location: "San Francisco",
    productType: "scooter",
  };

  let queryRunner: QueryRunner;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    queryRunner = dataSource.createQueryRunner();
  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    jest.clearAllMocks()
  })

  ....
  (queryRunner.manager.findOne as jest.Mock).mockResolvedValueOnce(mockLogistic3);
```

But when i call (queryRunner.manager.findOne as jest.Mock).mockResolvedValueOnce(mockLogistic3);, i receive an error saying that queryRunner is undefined

How can i mock and instantiate queryRunner correctly?